# correct use of Leibniz notation for the chain rule of a multivariable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, notation, partial-derivative

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ both be scaler-valued differentiable functions such that $f(x,y) = u$ and $g(u) = z$. Therefore, we can construct the function $h = g \circ f$ such that $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. If I wanted to apply the $\nabla$ operator to the function $h$, writing out the differentiation in Leibniz notation, would the following be correct? $$\nabla h = \frac{dg}{df}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx +  \frac{dg}{df}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

What I am concerned is incorrect is the use of the $d$'s and $\partial$'s. Would $$\nabla h = \frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx +  \frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

be the correct notation? If I am overcomplicating this procedure, please do not hesitate to share a simpler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla h$ is a covector with two components, so the $+$ in your first equation should be a comma:

$$\nabla h = \left(\frac{dg}{df}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} ,  \frac{dg}{df}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$

Alternatively, you can write it with a + in the following way:

$$\nabla h = \frac{dg}{df}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+  \frac{dg}{df}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

$dx,dy$ denote the covectors $(1,0), (0,1)$ respectively.

Comment: I see, I actually did not know it was a covector. However, my question was more about the use of the $d$'s and $\partial$'s. The reason for my two equations was to compare the two and ask which was the correct notation.

Comment: As far as the $d$'s and $\partial$'s, we have $g$ a function in one variable, so $\frac{dg}{df}$ is correct.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I also edited my question to include the covectors $dx$ and $dy$ as you mentioned.